# How to implement D3 charts with a rails application walkthrough

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js

Can someone please provide a basic walk-through/tutorial of implementing data from a rails application into D3 chart format? (e.g. want to turn the data from my index page into chart format)

I understand there is a way to do this via JSON, but I am not sure how to do it with multiple columns of data.

Comment: Since no one has answered you I'll recommend reading these: http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302 , http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961 ; What you need to notice is the render portion in the rails app. This rendering will be a file call that looks like bullet.json. JSON uses KEY, Value pairs so multiple columns is handled in the heirarchy. *Hope this helps